# a couple issues with VB, one is with the editor and the other with multiple address's

Tags: excel, vba

I am almost done with my email VB, but having a couple of issue:

The first is I have a cancel button on a prompt that is supposed to open the VB editor, but currently it does not. I have tried

```
If vbCancel Then Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True and If vbCancel Then Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True
```

Both do not open the editor.

The second issue is I can not seem to figure out is how to email a message from either C2 or D2 to multiple users?  I think it has something to do with the offset in bold but I'm not sure. Hopefully, this is almost done and close. Thank you :).

**VB**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sR As String
Dim sFile As String
Sheets("Email").Activate
Range("A1").Select
If MsgBox("Are there any issues to report", vbYesNoCancel) = vbYes Then
            Range("D2").Value = "x"
            MsgBox ("Please select an issue and save"), vbExclamation
Else
     Range("C2").Value = "x"
If vbCancel Then Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True


'define path
MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

' create connection, check condition, send email
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
With WS
    Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

 For Each c In Rng

Msg = "For " & WS.Cells(2, 2) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
For i = 3 To 4
    If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
        Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
    End If
Next

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            **.To = c.Offset(, 0)**
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
            .Body = Msg
            If Range("D2").Value & Chr(14) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
            .Send
        End With

Next c

'confirm message sent, clear sheet, and delete copy
MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
Range("C2:D2").ClearContents
Kill MyFileCopy

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

' Exit and do not save
Application.Quit
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some code to bring up a **dual window** state - half the screen *Excel* and the other half *VBA*:

```
Sub MAIN()
   Call dual
End Sub

Sub dual()
    Dim h As Long
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        x = Application.ActiveWindow.Width \ 2
        h = Application.ActiveWindow.Height
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Left = 545
        .Height = 550
        .Width = x * 0.9
        .Top = 0
        With .VBE.MainWindow
            .Width = 1.4 * x
            .Left = 0
            .Top = 0
            .Height = 740
            .WindowState = vbext_ws_Normal
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The "magic numbers" **545, 550, 740** are related to the physical dimension of my elderly Dell laptop.

Perhaps the code can be adapted to your use.